# Deallocating the memory of view once it is not on the screen in ARC

Tags: ios7, automatic-ref-counting, containers

I have a View controller with 4 buttons and one container view. And 4 other view controller which should be appear in container view when I click 4 different buttons. But when I keep on clicking on different buttons the app is crashing. The memory is not deallocating.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
self.view=nil;
```

}

This code I used for deallocating the view. But still it is consuming the memory. Is there any way to deallocate the view when it is not on the container view?
My container class have 4 buttons and one container, the code looks like this:

```
    - (IBAction)view1:(id)sender {


    pinkViewController *pink = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pink"];

    [self.containerView addSubview:pink.view];


}

- (IBAction)view2:(id)sender {
    redViewController *red = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"red"];
    [self.containerView addSubview:red.view];
}

- (IBAction)view3:(id)sender {
    orangeViewController *orange = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"orange"];
    [self.containerView addSubview:orange.view];
}

- (IBAction)view4:(id)sender {
    greenViewController *green = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"green"];
    [self.containerView addSubview:green.view];
}
```

Comment: make your all IBOutlet as weak `__weak IBOutlet UIButton *btn1`

Comment: You meant, All the outlets 'm using on the each view I should make it as weak and For buttons instead of using "id" have to use UIButton * ?

Comment: That didn't work. I have map inside the view, which is taking more memory and the app is crashing

Comment: are you adding map each time you click button? make sure you remove existing map before adding or add map once.

Comment: yeah. I have a ARCGIS map view on each and every view controller.So when I keep on clicking the different buttons , the memory it consumes are more. How can I take off the view out of memory when it is not on the container screen?

Comment: check if its already added in controller then dont add it again. you are creating new instance each time and adding it in controller. rather create a class level instance and add it once.

Comment: I have a container in which 'm displaying the maps of other view controller class when I click the button. So that container is displaying the maps. How do I deallocate it once it disappears from the container?

Comment: I have elaborated my question. Here Anything which 'm missing which is leading to memory leak?